# GeoServer - Key authentication module

Tags: geoserver

I'm running a geoserver and users have limited access to certain layers. 
Everything is running smooth, when a user is connecting the WMS via QGIS or ArcGIS.

The last step would be, that a user can login to a web application and watch the data, who he is allowed to. The application (based on Openlayers/JQuery/PHP) can already get layers from the Geoserver which are not protected.

The remaining problem is, that it is not possible to get secured layers (the GetCapabilites document only returns the free layers). Im dealing with this issue for a while but don't have a solution, yet.

How can I solve the authentication / authorization in my application? 
Is Authkey a possible solution: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/authkey/index.html? Where can I download the plugin - I can't find it on the page I posted?

Comment: Not sure it's what you search, but I've used the j_spring_security_check to login my users and used after the JSESSIONID in further request.

Comment: The user from my web application share the same user and password as Geoserver (common table). So when the user login, we log him to the web application and to Geoserver both at the same time.